# Representation of a finite dimensional division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As is well known the quaternion algebra $\mathbb H$ is isomorphic to a subring of the matrix ring $M_4(\mathbb R)$ over the reals. Now, let $\mathbb D$ be a finite dimensional division algebra over its center $\mathbb F$, say $[\mathbb D : \mathbb F]=d$. Can we proof that $\mathbb D$ is isomorphic to a subring of the matrix ring $M_d(\mathbb F)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, provided $\mathbb{D}$ is associative. Instead of a matrix ring let's use the ring $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{D})$ of $\mathbb{F}$-endomorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$ (as a vector space, not an algebra). Map $x\in \mathbb{D}$ to the linear transformation $\sigma_x:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ given by $\sigma_x(y)=xy$ for all $y\in\mathbb{D}$. Injectivity and the fact that this is an additive homomorphism is easy to prove. Multiplication requires the associativity. Since matrix multiplication is associative, this will not be an algebra homomorphism if $\mathbb{D}$ is not associative.

Comment: In fact, this is true of any associative unital algebra. That D is a division algebra is irrelevant here.